# How to create separated child table for each parent in onetomany relation

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

```
   @Entity
    public class Parent {
        @OneToMany(targetEntity = Child.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true,
                cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        protected Set<Child> childValueSets;    
    }
    @Entity
    public class Parent1 {
        @OneToMany(targetEntity = Child.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true,
                cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        protected Set<Child> childValueSets;
    }
    @Entity
    public class Child {
        private String abc;
    }
```

Right now the problem is one child table created for both entity parent and parent1.
I want to separate each child table for each parent and parent1 entity.